# @PropertySource working with spel (systemEnvironment and systemProperties)

Tags: spring, spring-3, spring-java-config, spring-4

I have in `src/main/resources` the following files

```
bpp-dev.properties
bpp-prod.properties
bpp-test.properties
```

Through my STS I can define the key **envB**, it in two places

1. how a `VM argument` such as `-DenvB=dev`
2. how an `Environment` such as **Variable** `envB` and **Value** `prod`

If in a `Configuration` class I have the following.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/manuel/jordan/properties/bpp-${envB}.properties")
public class PropertiesConfiguration {
```

It works fine but always has preference the `System Properties` over `Environment Variables`, it is the default behaviour. I have no problem here.

But if I want work explicitly with `Environment Variables`, the following fails

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/manuel/jordan/properties/bpp-#{systemEnvironment['envB']}.properties")
public class PropertiesConfiguration {
```

Always I receive:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
class path resource 
[com/manuel/jordan/properties/bpp-#{systemEnvironment['envB']}.properties]
cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

How I can fix this?

If I use the functional `@PropertySource` and just playing in the same `@Configuration` class I work with the following:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['envB']}")
private String propertiesEnvB;
@Value("#{systemEnvironment['envB']}")
private String environmentEnvB;
```

to be printed later, both works fine.